# eclipse is not generating apk file for any app developed in it?

Tags: android

I've been developing some applications in android using eclipse IDE.

All of those apps run fine on emulator but eclipse is not generating their .apk file and i am not able to install apps in any device.

Also its not giving any error or warning while running apps on emulator.

Please help me there.Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: What's happening ? what do you mean by not generating ? apk not showing where you are saving it or something else. Please explain.

Comment: how does that possible, you are able to run in emulator but its not generating your apk ! , can you tell me where should be APK file create ?

Comment: @Jibran Khan when i search for the apk file in the bin folder of my project its not shown anywhere there.

Comment: Check my answer below, if it is not generated by default, you have to generate the apk for a project.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If it is not generated itself, you have to right click on the project you want the apk for, then Android Tools will lead to the Exporting the apk file. You have to create a key one time and you can use it for future.

[image]

Comment: The apk file is generated in the bin folder when you run the application on device or emulator.

Comment: Yes but if it is not there then you can use the above method.

Answer (score 1):

When you run the project on the emulator, the .apk is generated on the bin directory. Keep in mind that just building the project (and not running it) will not output the apk file into the bin directory.
Have you checked the bin directory?

Comment: yes i have checked bin directory but apk file is not there, i know it is a weird problem. But i don't know why it is happening

Answer (score 0):

Right Click on Your Project-> Build Project

Check in your Bin folder, it will have your application apk file.

If you do not find it,try restarting your eclipse and building project.

To run application on your device, make sure your device is discovered and in Device Settings "Allow Mock Locations" is checked

Comment: Only building project doesn't generate apk file

Answer (score 0):

try to upgrade your ADT and SDK, I had a same problem this morning.

Google just introduced a new build system.

http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/eclipse-adt.html

Answer (score 0):

in eclipse from package explorer right click on your application -> Export ->Android -> export android application -> after this follow the steps from wizard and get your signed apk

Answer (score -2):

Try to switch off Antivir or firewall

Comment: And why should you do this? Please explain more

Comment: MY problem with .dex file solve this, I dont know Why: probably becouse Windows: