# Apk is not generated in android studio when ran

Tags: android, apk

I have tried a million different ways to get this work. I was able to generate an apk totally fine, then i switched out a few pictures for different ones and now when i compile/make/run the project no .apk is generated in the bin folder.

Any help would be great! I have tried using gradle to help but this also will not generate the apk.

Edit: I'm using Android studio

Comment: Did you check the Build folder for Output?

Comment: If it is not generated itself, you have to right click on the project you want the apk for, then Android Tools will lead to the Exporting the apk file. You have to create a key one time and you can use it further in your apk generation

Comment: Check its post for more details:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17017210/eclipse-is-not-generating-apk-file-for-any-app-developed-in-it

Comment: Do you use Android Studio or Eclipse?

Comment: I am using Android studio, sorry forgot to mention that. And I have a key generated already, but there is no option to export an apk. Everywhere I have looked it just says that you need to compile the program and it will generate the apk. When I do that it says "all files up to date" but nothing changes. I even tried deleting the old apk file in the bin folder and it still says all files up to date - but doesn't make a new apk file.

Comment: At top menu click on **Build -> Generate Signed apk**

Comment: @Apurva that option is greyed out

Comment: Have you downloaded gradle?

Comment: @Apurva I did last night but haven't gotten a chance to try using it, or figure out how it works

Comment: I had the same problem. The only way I could get the debug apk file generated was to run the assembleDebug task from the Gradle window. This will build the apk. However, if you use the Rebuild Project or Make Project menu the output folder will get deleted.